# Using set to avoid duplicate processing

Tags: python

I have a part in a code like below where file name is supplied to the loop iteratively. I want that no two file names with same name should
get processed ( to avoid duplicate processing) so I used the approach of "set" as above.

However this does not seem to work as expected. I get an empty processed_set and logic is not executed as expected.

```
else:
    create_folder(filename)
    processed_set=set()

    if xyz ==1:
        if filename not in processed_set:
          createdata(name)
          processed_set.add(filename)
        else:
          avoid_double_process(name)
```

Comment: You are creating `processed_set` each time the code is reached. Move its creation somewhere outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can infer from the code sample and guess based on function names, what you want to do is to avoid running the code if `filename` has already been processed.  You would do it this way:

```
processed_set = set() #initialize set outside of loop
for filename in filenames: #loop over some collection of filenames
    if filename not in processed_set: #check for non-membership
        processed_set.add(filename) #add to set since filename wasn't in the set
        create_folder(filename) #repositioned based on implied semantics of the name
        createdata(filename)
```

Alternatively, if `createdata` and `create_folder` are both functions you don't want to run multiple times for the same filename, you could create a filtering decorator.  If you actually care about the return value, you would want to use a memoizing decorator

```
def run_once(f):
    f.processed = set()
    def wrapper(filename):
        if filename not in f.processed:
        f.processed.add(filename)
        f(filename)
    return wrapper
```

then include `@run_once` on the line prior to your function definitions for the functions you only want to run once.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wanted to avoid the efforts in duplication of processing if the file has been processed once.The first code does the trick. Due to some limitations I cannot use the second method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build your set first, and then process the files in the set afterwards? the set will not add the same element if it is already present;

```
>>> myset  = { element for element in ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'def'] }
>>> myset
set(['abc', 'ghi', 'def'])
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more of your code might be helpful.  Not sure if this is the case, but your if conditional is in the same block as where you initialize

```
processed_set = set()
```

So basically if xyz != 1 then you are left with an empty set and nothing gets added to the set.  If you have a loop set up that hits the first else statement multiple times, you are clearing the contents of your set each time.

Again, I am not really sure of how your code flows since it is a bit obscure at the moment.  Add more of the surrounding code and it will be a bit easier for people to help you out.